# SeekBar to control image zoom

Tags: android

This is seekbar's onProgressChangeListener

```
package com.example.android.seekbartest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SeekBar sb;
ImageView iv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    sb = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean b) {
            float scale =  ((progress / 10.0f)+1);
            iv.setScaleX(scale);
            iv.setScaleY(scale);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

This is the XML of activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.android.seekbartest.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/test"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="15"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:maxHeight="40dp"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:thumbOffset="18dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the output

[image]

I want the image to be inside the fixed area even on zoom. But it is coming out of it. Any solution. Or else are there any other better ways to zoom the image in the specific area with seekbar?

Comment: Put the ImageView inside a layout with fixed width/height

Comment: give the imageview fixed width and height and  scaleType centerInside

Comment: @MuratK. I will not know the device resolution right. The image should match the parent width and height should be relevant in all the devices it runs.

Comment: @lelloman I will not know the device resolution right. The image should match the parent width and height should be relevant in all the devices it runs.

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar issue changed(10 to 100) and it worked for me

```
float scale = ((progress / 100.0f) + 1);
              iv.setScaleX(scale);
                    iv.setScaleY(scale);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.android.seekbartest.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
<!-- Add the height and width over here, so that your image view doesnot exceed the LinearLayout frame -->
<ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/test"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" /></LinearLayout>

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="15"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:maxHeight="40dp"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:thumbOffset="18dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I will not know the device resolution right. The image should match the parent width and height should be relevant in all the devices it runs.

Comment: You can set the width through programitically of the LinearLayout! or you may choose to select certain `height` of the layout. and keep the `match-parent` for the `width`